# Why isn't Angular2 part of my replicated npm repository?

Tags: node.js, npm, angular

I successfully managed to get a private npm server up and running, which resides inside a Ubuntu VM on my Windows 10 machine.

I replicated the npm repository using `https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry` as a source for CouchDB and can query packages such as `jquery` from my Windows 10 machine just fine.

```
PS D:\Sources\NodeJS\test> npm view jquery

{ name: 'jquery',
  description: 'JavaScript library for DOM operations',
  'dist-tags': { beta: '3.0.0-rc1', latest: '2.2.4' },
  ...
  gitHead: 'c0185ab7c75aab88762c5aae780b9d83b80eda72',
  dist:
   { shasum: '2c89d6889b5eac522a7eea32c14521559c6cbf02',
     tarball: 'http://registry.npmjs.org/jquery/-/jquery-2.2.4.tgz' },
  directories: {} }
```

However, all of the `@angular/*` packages appear to be missing. If I point npm to `skimdb` directly I get the exact same result, so it can't be a problem with replication.

```
PS D:\Sources\NodeJS\test> npm view @angular/common
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "view" "@angular/common"
npm ERR! node v5.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.7.3
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @angular/common
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@angular/common' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\Sources\NodeJS\test\npm-debug.log
```

Is this the proper registry to start with?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this appears to boil down to *scoped packages* where `@angular` is some kind of namespace.

I solved this problem by pointing to the official repository for packages from the `@angular` scope, i.e. my `.npmrc` now looks as follows:

```
registry=http://<couchdb server ip>:5984/registry/_design/app/_rewrite
@angular:registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
```